# making your own malloc function?

Tags: c, malloc

I read that some games rewrite their own malloc to be more efficient. I don't understand how this is possible in a virtual memory world. If I recall correctly, malloc actually calls an OS specific function, which maps the virtual address to a real address with the MMU. So then how can someone make their own memory allocator and allocate real memory, without calling the actual runtime's malloc?

Thanks

Comment: most likely they are pre-allocating a large block of memory (a "memory arena") which avoids fragmentation and allows for better allocation performance

Comment: Yup, you can ask the OS for a large chunk of contiguous memory Milo.  It's pretty common in the systems world.

Comment: yeah, what they most likely do is write a wrapper around malloc that they use instead of calling malloc directly, which does increase speed in some cases, but does not replace the OS level stuff

Comment: If they're really rewriting `malloc` and not just using special-purpose pools on top of `malloc`, I think it's just a matter of them being stupid.

Comment: @R..: really? What I used to hear was that the first thing you did on unpacking the PS2 devkit was, you wrote your own version of `malloc` (or copied it from a previous game). I think Sony shipped one, but it was widely regarded as unfit for any purpose, even building your own allocation tools on top of.

Comment: @Steve: Indeed, I forgot about consoles. I have no idea how bad their standard library implementations are, but I suspect you're right.

Comment: @R..: the current generation of consoles are probably better, since the game runs under the OS rather than replacing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to make my own Malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732617/i-want-to-make-my-own-malloc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's certainly possible to write an allocator more efficient than a general purpose one.

If you know the properties of your allocations, you can blow general purpose allocators out of the water.

Case in point: many years ago, we had to design and code up a communication subsystem (HDLC, X.25 and proprietary layers) for embedded systems. The fact that we knew the maximum allocation would always be less than 128 bytes (or something like that) meant that we didn't have to mess around with variable sized blocks at all. *Every* allocation was for 128 bytes no matter how much you asked for.

Of course, if you asked for more, it returned NULL.

By using fixed-length blocks, we were able to speed up allocations and de-allocations greatly, using bitmaps and associated structures to hold accounting information rather than relying on slower linked lists. In addition, the need to coalesce freed blocks was not needed.

Granted, this was a special case but you'll find that's so for games as well. In fact, we've even used this in a general purpose system where allocations below a certain threshold got a fixed amount of memory from a self-managed pre-allocated pool done the same way. Any other allocations (larger than the threshold or if the pool was fully allocated) were sent through to the "real" `malloc`.

Comment: A general-purpose allocator using the right binning algorithms is just as fast and much more powerful as long as you don't have to deal with threads. I'll grant that your bitmaps and such might be faster and/or simpler once concurrency comes into play, though.

Comment: A general purpose allocator will almost always (I think it's always always, myself, but I won't be that arrogant) be beaten by one which has the advantage of extra knowledge. Going along the reductio ad absurdum line, if you know only one allocation wil ever be active at a time and it will always be less than 1K, you can just have a static buffer in your malloc :-) There is _no_ binning allocator that can outperform that. You are right in that it's a trade-off, flexibility against speed, but that's where the question was coming from - games probably don't need all that flexibility.

Comment: I wrote a comprehensive study on this topic. The take-home point is that the performance benefits of custom memory allocators are often lower than advertised when compared against a state-of-the-art memory allocator. See http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/berger-oopsla2002.pdf

Comment: I'll defer to you on that one @Emery, since you've done an investigation more thorough than the one we did. We _did_ find that our custom allocator (like two of those in your study) was a lot better than the general purpose one but the state of the art may have improved a lot by then. As with all optimisations, _measure, don't guess._

Answer (score 3):

In general, malloc will call an OS-specific function to obtain a bunch of memory (at least one VM page), and will then divide that memory up into smaller chunks as needed to return to the caller of malloc.

The malloc library will also have a list (or lists) of free blocks, so it can often meet a request without asking the OS for more memory. Determining how many different block sizes to handle, deciding whether to attempt to combine adjacent free blocks, and so forth, are the choices the malloc library implementor has to make.

It's possible for you to bypass the malloc library and directly invoke the OS-level "give me some memory" function and do your own allocation/freeing within the memory you get from the OS. Such implementations are likely to be OS-specific. Another alternative is to use malloc for initial allocations, but maintain your own cache of freed objects.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is have your allocator allocate a pool of memory, then service requests from than (and allocate a bigger pool if it runs out). I'm not sure if that's what they're doing though.

Answer (score 2):

Just because `malloc()` is a standard C function doesn't mean that it's the lowest level access you have to the memory system.  In fact, `malloc()` is probably implemented in terms of lower-level operating system functionality.  That means you could call those lower level interfaces too.  They might be OS-specific, but they might allow you better performance than you would get from the `malloc()` interface.  If that were the case, you could implement your own memory allocation system any way you want, and maybe be even more efficient about it - optimizing the algorithm for the characteristics of the size and frequency of allocations you're going to make, for example.

Answer (score 2):

> If I recall correctly, malloc actually
>   calls an OS specific function

Not quite. Most hardware has a 4KB page size. Operating systems generally don't expose a memory allocation interface offering anything smaller than page-sized (and page-aligned) chunks.

`malloc` spends most of its time managing the virtual memory space that has already been allocated, and only occasionally requests more memory from the OS (obviously this depends on the size of the items you allocate and how often you `free`).

There is a common misconception that when you `free` something it is immediately returned to the operating system. While this sometimes occurs (particularly for larger memory blocks) it is generally the case that `free`d memory remains allocated to the process and can then be re-used by later `malloc`s.

So most of the work is in bookkeeping of already-allocated virtual space. Allocation strategies can have many aims, such as fast operation, low memory wastage, good locality, space for dynamic growth (e.g. `realloc`) and so on.

If you know more about your pattern of memory allocation and release, you can optimise `malloc` and `free` for your usage patterns or provide a more extensive interface.

For instance, you may be allocating lots of equal-sized objects, which may change the optimal allocation parameters. Or you may always free large amounts of objects at once, in which case you don't want `free` to be doing fancy things.

Have a look at [memory pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) and [obstacks](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Obstacks.html).

Answer (score 1):

See [How do games like GTA IV not fragment the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687643/how-do-games-like-gta-iv-not-fragment-the-heap).